# More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression but only in function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

When I use a function it gives mentioned error, but when same code is used alone it works just fine. Where is the problem here?

Fiddle with function: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c4b0c8a59d2bd851284ed624ab1c335d

Fidle with clean select: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7ccca6c70061aff1f6c394815aa8e9b1

Sample data:

```
create table report
(report_day date,
 tickets_no integer,
 tickets_stake numeric,
 promo_tickets_no integer,
 promo_tickets_stake numeric,
 group_id integer);
 
 insert into report
 values
 ('2020-07-20',12,569.6, 2, 44,1),
 ('2020-07-20',61,2000, 5, 260,2),
  ('2020-07-21',35,1244.2, 11, 250,1),
  ('2020-07-21',100,2500.5, 29, 575,2),
   ('2020-07-22',66,2511.8, 23, 670,1),
   ('2020-07-22',125,3358.2, 50, 990,2);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report(arguments json)
  RETURNS json AS
$BODY$
     
DECLARE 
        
    dateFrom date;
    dateTo date;
        selectedType integer;
BEGIN 
        
    dateFrom := cast(arguments->>'dateFrom' as date);
    dateTo := cast(arguments->>'dateTo' as date);
    selectedType := cast(arguments->>'selectedType' as integer);

RETURN (
    WITH full_data as (
 with tickets as (
  select 
    report_day
  , sum(tickets_no) as tickets_no
  , sum(tickets_stake) as tickets_stake
  FROM report
  WHERE selectedType = 0
  AND report_day between dateFrom and dateTo
  GROUP BY 1)
  
, promo_tickets as (
  select 
    report_day
  , sum(promo_tickets_no) as promo_tickets_no
  , sum(promo_tickets_stake) as promo_tickets_stake
  FROM report
  WHERE selectedType = 1
  AND report_day between dateFrom and dateTo
  GROUP BY 1)
  
  select 
    t.report_day 
  , sum(coalesce(t.tickets_no,0) + coalesce(pt.promo_tickets_no,0)) as tickets_no                             
  , sum(coalesce(t.tickets_stake,0) + coalesce(pt.promo_tickets_stake,0)) as tickets_no
  FROM tickets t
  LEFT JOIN promo_tickets pt on t.report_day = pt.report_day                                    
   GROUP BY 1
   ORDER BY 1)
        
select row_to_json(full_data) from full_data
);

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
  
  select * from report(json_build_object('dateFrom', '2020-07-20', 'dateTo', '2020-07-22','selectedType', 0 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your function to return an array of report objects as your query does, then change this part:

```
select row_to_json(full_data) from full_data
```

To aggregate the rows into an array:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(full_data)) from full_data
```

If you want the function to return multiple rows, then you need to make two changes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report(arguments json)
  RETURNS table (row_to_json json) AS
```

And for the `return`:

```
RETURN QUERY (
    WITH full_data as (
```

Updated [fiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=345aacd798ad5ce8af8e8941eaeb1a1f)

Comment: Isn't it possible to return multiple json rows?

Comment: @sh4rkyy  Not if your function return type is `json`.  Please see update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to return more than one rows from a function where just one row should be returned. Add One more parameter to your function preferably a primary key column ( I suppose `tickets_no` ) such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report(arguments json, i_tickets_no int)
```

and rewrite the query as

```
WITH full_data AS
 (WITH tickets AS
     (SELECT report_day,
            SUM(tickets_no) AS tickets_no,
            SUM(tickets_stake) AS tickets_stake
       FROM report
      WHERE selectedType = 0
        AND report_day BETWEEN dateFrom AND dateTo
        AND tickets_no = i_tickets_no
      GROUP BY 1),
    promo_tickets as
     (select report_day,
            SUM(promo_tickets_no) as promo_tickets_no,
            SUM(promo_tickets_stake) as promo_tickets_stake
       FROM report
      WHERE selectedType = 1
        AND report_day BETWEEN dateFrom AND dateTo
      GROUP BY 1)
    
    select t.report_day,
           SUM(COALESCE(t.tickets_no, 0) + COALESCE(pt.promo_tickets_no, 0)) AS tickets_no,
           SUM(COALESCE(t.tickets_stake, 0) +
               COALESCE(pt.promo_tickets_stake, 0)) AS tickets_no
      FROM tickets t
      LEFT JOIN promo_tickets pt
        ON t.report_day = pt.report_day
     GROUP BY 1
     ORDER BY 1)
```

and call by adding this second argument.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=544c0613cd0b797a9102567957e138f3)</kbd>